# SSAS build without user/password in the connection string

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, business-intelligence

I am losing my user/password information when I generate the bin files in the Visual Studio( .asdatabase, .configsettings, .deploymentoptions, .deploymentttargets, .assecurityinformation ), I need to pass these bin files to another team member install/deploy these files in production using the deployment wizard. I have 2 problems:

Problem 1: The ConnectionString of the Data Source is losing the User ID/Password value configured in Visual Studio, and need to manually add this values in Deployment Wizard.

Problem 2: After manually add this values in Deployment Wizard, the XMLA deploy script originated by Deployment Wizard losses the User ID/Password value in the connection string, needing another manually intervention, now in the XMLA deploy script.

What I want: Configure the connection string in Visual Studio,  build the project, and pass the bin files to another person use the deployment wizard only 'next, next, finish' to generate the XMLA script and run the script, without any manual intervention. If problem 1 is impossible to resolve, at least the XLMA deploy script with the User ID/Password information without manually intervention( problem 2 ) would help me a lot.

My Data Source in Visual Studio is configured as Inherit( I already tried service account, doesn't work ) and save password.
I change the Project configuration in Visual Studio 'RemovePassword' to False, doesn't work too.

My Visual Studio version is 2017, my Analysis Services version is 2014. my SQL Server version is 2014 too and Deployment Wizard 2014 too.

Thank You

Comment: You need to use the deployment wizard option that doesn't deploy the connection. Just leaves it as-is

Comment: Nick.I am using the deployment wizard to generate the XLMA Script, after that I am putting manually the ConnectionPassword. With that, the other team only need to run the XLMA without do nothing. I asked Microsoft and they said that is impossible generate scripts with password, because Microsoft policies

Comment: My mistake there is no option to do this in the deployment wizrad. AAS deployment support is very disappointing butyou could try following this, which shows how to include the connection string when deploying: https://medium.com/swlh/you-me-ci-cd-deploying-azure-analysis-services-tabular-models-through-azure-pipelines-55370ac9fab3